# Add name to create ec2 snapshot python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, backup

I am a novice at Python but am learning as I go. I found this script and it works well but I wanted to make some edits to it so that it also saves the name of the instance that it created a snapshot for.

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime

#allows Python developers to write software that makes use of Amazon services like S3 and EC2
ec = boto3.client('ec2')

#finds tags-keys with the name "backup" or "Backup"
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['backup', 'Backup']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = [
        i for r in reservations
        for i in r['Instances']
    ]

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    #find tag-keys with the name Retention default value if NULL is 7 days
    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7

        for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                continue
            vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
            print "Found EBS volume %s on instance %s" % (
                vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

            snap = ec.create_snapshot(
                VolumeId=vol_id,
            )

            to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

            print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days" % (
                snap['SnapshotId'],
                vol_id,
                instance['InstanceId'],
                retention_days,
            )

    #set retention days according to the value int input
    for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print "Will delete %d snapshots on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
            ]
        )
```

So far I have this but am a little lost as to how to make it work in with the current script above:

```
snapshot = ec(to_tag['SnapshotId'])
volumename = ''

# Add volume name to snapshot for easier identification
snapshot.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': volumename}])
```

Any ideas welcomed! Thanks.

```
import boto3
import collections
import datetime

#allows Python developers to write software that makes use of Amazon services like S3 and EC2
ec = boto3.client('ec2')
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

#finds tags-keys with the name "backup" or "Backup"
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = ec.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['backup', 'Backup']},
        ]
    ).get(
        'Reservations', []
    )

    instances = [
        i for r in reservations
        for i in r['Instances']
    ]

    print "Found %d instances that need backing up" % len(instances)

    to_tag = collections.defaultdict(list)

    #find tag-keys with the name Retention default value if NULL is 7 days
    for instance in instances:
        try:
            retention_days = [
                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
        except IndexError:
            retention_days = 7

        for dev in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            if dev.get('Ebs', None) is None:
                continue
            vol_id = dev['Ebs']['VolumeId']
            print "Found EBS volume %s on instance %s" % (
                vol_id, instance['InstanceId'])

    volumes = ec2_client.describe_volumes()
    volumes = volumes["Volumes"]


    volumes_list = []

    for volume in volumes:
        volumes_list.append([volume["Tags"][0]["Value"], volume["VolumeId"]])

    for volume in volumes_list:
        try:
            create_snapshot_response = ec2_client.create_snapshot(
                    VolumeId=volume[1],
                    Description=volume[0] + " " + str(datetime.now()).split(" ")[0],
            )

            snapshot_id = create_snapshot_response["SnapshotId"]
            tags = ec2_client.create_tags(
                Resources=[snapshot_id],
                Tags=[{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "{}: {}".format(volume[0], str(datetime.now()).split(" ")[0])
                }]
            )

            to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])

            print "Retaining snapshot %s of volume %s from instance %s for %d days" % (
                snap['SnapshotId'],
                vol_id,
                instance['InstanceId'],
                retention_days,
            )

    #set retention days according to the value int input
    for retention_days in to_tag.keys():
        delete_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=retention_days)
        delete_fmt = delete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print "Will delete %d snapshots on %s" % (len(to_tag[retention_days]), delete_fmt)
        ec.create_tags(
            Resources=to_tag[retention_days],
            Tags=[
                {'Key': 'DeleteOn', 'Value': delete_fmt},
            ]
        )
```

Comment: `create_snapshot` boto call has a parameter called TagSpecifications through which you can create the Name tag when creating the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaKumarR, I'm not sure on how to use use this parameter. Would you be able to hold my hand through this or guide me in making it applicable to the code? Perhaps maybe some "for dummy" resources? xD

Comment: I have added it as answer. Please replace lines 43-45 with the mentioned lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instances = ec2_client.describe_instances()['Reservations']


    for i in instances:
        try:
            create_snapshot_response = ec2_client.create_snapshot(
                VolumeId=i['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]
            )

            snapshot_id = create_snapshot_response["SnapshotId"]
            tags = ec2_client.create_tags(
                Resources=[snapshot_id],
                Tags=[{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "{}".format(i['Instances'][0]["Tags"][0]['Value'])
                }]
            )

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return "Success"
```

Comment: You can definitely create that. Refer this boto3 document: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_snapshot

Comment: `ResourceType (string) --
The type of resource to tag. Currently, the resource types that support tagging on creation are instance and volume .` Read this in create_snapshot() mate

Comment: @Lgalan90 Did you try my snippet?, I am damn sure that this works even locally or lambda. If you are using boto3, running location shouldn't matter

Comment: As Venkata mentioned, you need to do this way. The version of botocore installed in Lambda containers is not the latest and you can't do it the other way currently. The latest version of botocore (1.8.50) supports creation of tags at the time of snapshot creation.

Comment: @VenkataSSKrishnaManikeswar I have also tried your code just in case but perhaps I did not set it up properly...

Comment: Good morning! I played around with the code and got the Name to display the volume name. Would you happen to know what code I'd need to write to capture the EC2's name instead? Here is the error I'm receiving now:   File "/var/task/backup.py", line 57, in lambda_handler
    to_tag[retention_days].append(snap['SnapshotId'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Also, I've updated the script in my question to match my current code.

Comment: You will get `Tags` key in `describe_instances` API call, You can easily get your instances name there and add it as value to your `snapshot`. Coming to your error, check what exactly does your `snap` field contains and try to reference it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is the article I followed to setup automated snapshots, the python code I'm trying to update is from here as well: https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/

Comment: Check my updated answer, it cannot be simple than this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165995/discussion-between-lgalan90-and-venkata-s-s-krishna-manikeswar).

Answer (score 1):

Krishna did what I have in my lambda for providing instance names on my snapshots....one change i had was

```
instance_name = ""
if 'Tags' in instance:
for tag in instance['Tags']:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
        instance_name = tag['Value']
if not instance_name:
    instance_name = instance['InstanceId']


snap = ec.create_snapshot(
VolumeId=vol_id,
TagSpecifications=[{
    'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
    'Tags': [{
        'Key': 'Name',
        'Value': instance_name
    }]
}]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon, what part of the script did you replace your code with to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Update lines 43-45 to following:

```
instance_name = ""
if 'Tags' in instance:
    for tag in instance['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            instance_name = tag['Value']
if not instance_name:
    instance_name = instance['InstanceId']

snap = ec.create_snapshot(
    VolumeId=vol_id,
    TagSpecifications=[{
        'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
        'Tags': [{
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': instance['InstanceId']
        }]
    }]
)
```

Comment: I replaced the line: snap = ec.create_snapshot(VolumeId=vol_id,) with the same amount of indentation but received an error: "Unknown parameter in input: 'TagSpecifications', must be one of: Description, VolumeId, DryRun: ParamValidationError"

Comment: Are you running this in lambda or locally? If you are running this locally, update your boto3 library

Comment: I am running it on Lambda, I have added how my new code looks at the bottom of my questions for visual reference.